# Rewrite up to three folders into three query string parameters to a PHP script

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, custom-variables

I'd like to use mod_rewrite within the `.htaccess` file to rewrite folders to a `var string`. Below is examples of current and what I would prefer.

- *Current URL*: `example.com/main/folder1/folder2/folder3`
- *Preferred URL*: `example.com/parser.php?var1=folder1&var2=folder2&var3=folder3`

How can I rewrite the current URL's to preferred URLs?

Comment: Are there always exactly three levels of folder?  If there are always exactly three it isn't a hard problem.   If there a are "up to three" it is trickier, but still doable (you might need a separate rule for when there is one, then another when there are two, etc).   If there are an arbitrary number, I don't believe that mod_rewrite can do it.

Comment: Just to note, as per the original question (before the edit), a "301 redirect" is probably not what you want. You probably mean an "internal rewrite". ie. the URL `example.com/main/folder1/folder2/folder3` should remain in the address bar - is that correct?

Comment: Yes internal rewrite not 301.

the first level [link]example.com/main/folder1 will have link to the folder2 and the folder2 link to folder 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use these three rewrite rules which handle up to 3 levels of directories:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? /parser.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^main\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  /parser.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^main\/([^\/]+)\/?  /parser.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

In those regular expressions:

- `^main\/`: starts with "main/"
- `([^\/]+)`: a bunch of characters that are not slashes (in a capturing group to be pulled out with `$1`, `$2`, or `$3`)
- `\/?` an optional ending slash
- `[L]` the last rewrite rule (so that later rewrite rules don't *also* get triggered)

I usually prefer to pass all the folders as a single variable like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main\/(.*) /parser.php?folders=$1
```

then your PHP parser could split the folders on the slash to get the three variables you want.